What is the procedure for Sandhyavandanam for a Krsna-Yajurvedin Nambudiri of the Taittiriya Sakha and Baudhayana Sutra?
Please inform me, what is the exact procedure of Prataha, Madhyandinah, and Sayam Sandhyavandanam for a Krsna-Yajurvedin Nambudiri Brahmin of the Taittirya Sakha and the Baudhayana Sutra?

Ask any Priest of your sect..You may even get a printed guide for your sect..
